# How can I add consecutive number identifiers to new instances of objects?

Tags: python

I'm implementing R-Trees on Python, in secondary memory. I need to keep a file of the nodes, so I want to enumerate them for easy access and so I can create a file with the rectangles on each node. What I want to do is, every time I create a node, to give it an "id" which is a consecutive number.

I tried defining a global variable before and after my class definitions, but that doesn't seem to work. Even if I define it as global, when I try to create a Node, there's an error in **init** because "nodeId" is not defined, specifically when I try to add 1 to the variable:

```
global nodePath, path, nodeId
...
nodeId = 0

class Node:
    def __init__(self, tag, t, n, inputFile, id = nodeId, init = True):
        ...
        self.id = id
        nodeId += 1
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have needed `global nodeId` in your function definition, but it makes more sense conceptually to have it as a class variable.

```
class Node:
    nodeId = 0
    def __init__(self, tag, t, n, inputFile, init = True):
        ...
        self.id = Node.nodeId
        Node.nodeId += 1
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right, this makes much more sense and works perfectly :)